# Linker Error - Im unsure of how to proceed

Tags: c, linker-errors, cs50

I am trying to compile the code for dictionary.c so I can continue onto testing. The only problem is that each time I try to use the make command to compile it i keep on getting the error

```
speller/ $ make
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file speller: Is a directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:4: speller] Error 1
```

I can imagine that part of the problem is the name of the directory being speller but im overall not very sure of what all I need to do to resolve this error

Any assistance or tips would be greatly appreciated!

I am unsure of what to try to fix it since it seems to be a really broad error

Comment: we need to see the make file

Comment: The problem seems to be that you created a subdirectory that has the same name as the program you're trying to compile. Either remove or rename the `speller` directory.

Comment: IIRC, cs50 has its own script to compile/link/go??? Otherwise, please _edit_ your question and post your `Makefile` in a separate code block here. Also, from the _same_ directory that you do/did `make`, post the output of `ls -lR` in another code block here. I suspect that your makefile is trying to do (e.g.) `cc -o speller speller.c` but somebody/something already did `mkdir speller`. Or, you're running the script/Makefile from the wrong directory and you should do `cd speller` before doing `make`???

Comment: turns out there was a directory that i somehow didnt properly recognize was in the main directory. After removing it the error went away

Thank You @Barmar

Ill also be sure to include more actual code next time I post haha